# Incorporating google sign in into React Native project with Expo

Tags: react-native, expo, google-signin

I am trying to add google sign in, and I've tried already, but I'm getting an error that it doesn't operate in the Expo client. Is this only solvable by downloading the ipa or apk file, making the standalone app every time I want to test my app? How do people incorporate methods of authentication from google, facebook, etc into their react native mobile app within expo?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using Google Firebase. Firebase supports login with Google, Facebook, Twitter, etc.